# We will and we have in the same sentence

Tags: verbs, tenses

Trying to write a sentence as follows:

> Of course, we will, and have already, try to respond promptly.

My problem is connecting the word *try* with *we will* and *have already*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "We will try, and have already done so"? The term 'promptly' seems odd in context.  Presumably the attempt to respond was prompt but unsuccessful?

Comment: I'm not sure the meaning of the sentence is clear, as written

Comment: It doesn't work because there is no consistency.  You can't make the language consistent if the meaning isn't consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The parallelism doesn't work because it requires different forms of *try*: *will try* but *have tried*. (Parallel structures that split compound verb phrases, even if technically correct, can be difficult to read anyway.) Your intended meaning is also a bit unclear: I don't know what distinguishes an attempt to respond from an actual response. Maybe something like this is better?

> We've already tried to respond to you, and we'll try again soon.

Or if you're discussing not one particular response but a general policy of responding quickly, maybe:

> We promise to respond promptly to all requests, just as we always have done.